# Unexpected token )

Tags: javascript

I keep getting the error in the title when trying to run this from the google chrome console.

```
var Usernames = ["Sinblade"];
var Password = ["******"];
var AccountNum = 0;
var gameID    = 000000; // Put your game ID here

for (AccountNum < Usernames.length; AccountNum++){
    document.getElementById("LoginUsername").value = Usernames[AccountNum];
    document.getElementById("LoginPassword").value = Password;
    document.getElementById('LoginButton').submit();
}
```

Comment: Oops the full error is:  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )" didn't think it got it all.

Comment: Try `for (;AccountNum < Usernames.length; AccountNum++)`. Also, the convention is lowercase variables.

Comment: for( ; AcountNum < ...etc.

Comment: Your for loop is wrong `for (var AccountNum = 0; AccountNum< Usernames.length; AccountNum++){`

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop is missing the initialize clause.

If you don't want to do any initialization just leave it empty:

```
for (;AccountNum < Usernames.length; AccountNum++){
```

Comment: I used that one, but now I am getting the error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function? When I change submit() to click() it just says undefined.

Comment: @sinblade In `document.getElementById('LoginButton').submit();` you're supposed to be referencing the form to do `.submit()`, not the submit button.

Comment: @sinblade: `.submit` is a method of `<form>` elements. If `#LoginButton` is not a `<form>` element you get an error.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how a `for` loop works: you need to initialize the iterator in it (there is a workaround but not recommended)

```
var Usernames = ["Sinblade"];
var Password = ["******"];
var gameID    = 000000; // Put your game ID here

for (var AccountNum = 0; AccountNum < Usernames.length; AccountNum++){
  document.getElementById("LoginUsername").value = Usernames[AccountNum];
  document.getElementById("LoginPassword").value = Password;
  document.getElementById('LoginButton').submit();
}
```

Comment: To be pedantic, AccoutNum should be preceded with a `var` ;)

Comment: You could simplify this to to `for (; AccountNum < Usernames.length; AccountNum++)`

Comment: @AlienWebguy:  Yes, but given the OP is obviously pretty new it's probably better to write it all out.

Comment: @krtek I was editing that while your posted your comment :) @AlienWebguy nothing justifies to do that in this code, that would simply make it less readable. Also in the next ES version the scope of `AccountNum` should be limited to the loop so better get used to do it properly.

Comment: @floribon I didn't know that, which version of ES is that?

Comment: @Pluto EcmaScript 6 introduces the `let` keyword to reduce the scope of a variable to its block-level instead of function-level (as in many other languages). Read more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Ah I see. I was a little surprised at first because your comment made it sound like they were changing the functionality for `var` since that's what you used in your example.